# APA6 document class: Second table gets centered vertically

Tags: tables, floats, apa6, threeparttable

I'm currently stuck with the problem that my second table gets centered vertically when using the apa6 document class. What I would like is the second table on a new page but at the top, just like the first one. Please see the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,noextraspace,12pt]{apa6}

\shorttitle{test}

\begin{document}

See \ref{tab:test1} and \ref{tab:test2}. 

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{test1}
    \label{tab:test1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
      a & 1  & 2 \\
      a & 1  & 2 \\
      a & 1  & 2 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{test2}
    \label{tab:test2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
      a & 1  & 2 \\
      a & 1  & 2 \\
      a & 1  & 2 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'm not very proficient in LaTeX, so I googled this problem and tried some different combinations of [htbp], using `\newline` and/or `\clearpage` between the tables and even putting the two `threeparttables` in the one `table` part. But none of this worked, the last one always puts them on the same page, even with  `\newline` in between.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and how to resolve it? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Great question! As someone who uses APA6 myself, I frequently run into this problem. What LaTeX program/IDE are you using? I compiled your code on Overleaf and it prints as you described in your question. Perhaps give that a try? I know it is going to be a bit annoying with uploading and downloading. But, I hope it helps!

Comment: My answer is, more directly speaking -- run it in Overleaf because there are variations in programs that cause this problem. What the OP is asking for can be achieved via Overleaf.

Comment: overleaf do not change the latex sources so running or not running on overleaf can not affect this. They use (I think) texlive 2017 so in principle there could be differences with a newer installation

Comment: With all due respect, I ran the MWE in a TeX app on my local computer, and again on Overleaf. Desirable results came from Overleaf and not my local TeX app.

Comment: Thank you very much Jennifer! You are right, it works on Overleaf, so I'll try to update/change my local version.

Comment: I could track the issue down to version 2.6 (2018/03/24) of `endfloat`. Overleaf is still using an older version of that package (`2011/12/25 v2.5d`) where the output is as expected by the OP. With a newer version of the package the output is the undesirable centred table. I have not yet found out why that is, but this should be a start for the investigation...

Comment: I'll try to get this version right now @moewe . Thanks a lot!